# Confirmation box pops up more than once using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax to delete records and display an animated message (function display_message) when this record is deleted, but I noticed that the confirmation box pops up depending on the number of records. for example if I have 2 records in my list and I want to delete on of them.The confirmation box pops up twice before deleting and the same thing happen with the message, It appears twice(I'm using a message that fade in and out),
and so on(3 records -> 3 pops up, etc). I tried a lot to resolve it but I haven't succeed .
Here is my function that delete the records:

```
$(function() {
$(".delete_class").click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
if(confirm("are you sure?")) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "delete.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function()
    {
   parent.hide();
    }
 });
}
display_message("user deleted!")
}); 
});
```

Please help.

EDIT: here is the display_message function:

```
function display_message(msg) {
  $(".success").html(msg).effect("drop", { mode: "show", direction: "up" }, function( {
     window.timer = function() {
       $(".success").effect("drop", { mode: "hide", direction: "up"});
     }
window.setTimeout("window.timer()", 3000);
  }
 )
```

}

Comment: Indenting is allowed in Javascript...

Comment: We'll need to see the display_message code

Comment: how many times does this block of code end up in your rendered html?

Comment: If the confirm box is happening multiple times, you are binding/triggering the event multiple times. We can't tell how with just the code you have provided. Please provide more.

Comment: you don't need to define `timer` on `window`, just do `setTimeout(function(){ ... timer code here ... },3000);` Still not enough context to figure out why `confirm` is happening multiple times.

Comment: So what other code should I provide to let you figure out what's going on ? :s

Answer (score 0):

```
function display_message(msg) {
    $(".success").stop().html(msg).effect("drop", { mode: "show", direction: "up" }, function({
        window.timer = function() {
            $(".success").effect("drop", { mode: "hide", direction: "up"});
    } window.setTimeout("window.timer()", 3000);
});
```

I think you can invoke `stop()` to only trigger last animation as a work around...

Comment: I solved my problem by adding $(".delete_class").unbind("click").click(function ()